# with javascript how to open an image from usb mobile

Tags: javascript, file, mobile, path, usb

i have an mtk mobile, it is connected to my computer
after taking a screenshot i want to open this screenshot in my computer using javascript language.
when i tried to open file the browser didnt found it because i dont know how is the right path of this file
this is correct path but it is not working:
pc\mtk6589_wet_lca\Phone storage\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot_2017-09-29-00-42-58.PNG

and this is the code that i am using to open the image:

```
<script>
function show()
{
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "pc\mtk6589_wet_lca\Phone storage\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot_2017-09-29-00-42-58.PNG";
//img.src = "e:\lewis.PNG";
img.alt = "my image";
document.body.appendChild(img);
}
</script>
<body>
<button onclick="show();">show image</button>
</body>
```

when i tried "e:\lewis.PNG" it is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

from the `e:\` drive naming i conclude that you are on windows

on windows `pc\mtk6589_wet_lca\Phone storage\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot_2017-09-29-00-42-58.PNG` is not a valid path. a valid path begins with a letter like `c:,...` i do not know what drive letter is assigned for your mtks internal storage, you have to add this drive letter in the path ( if there is one )

if there is only a drive letter assigned by windows for your SD card on the phone ( not for its internal storage ) the internal storage can only be accessed using MTP ( Media Transfer Protocol ), PTP ( Picture Transfer Protocol ), ...:

https://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/

on my own MTK phone ( Doogee X5 MTK 6580 not the PRO version ) i can access internal storage only using MTP and PTP. i can switch this when i attach it to USB and slide on the screen from most top downwards, there appears a menu with USB options where i can choose between *mass storage*, *MTP*, *PTP* and *power-only* mode.

on windows MTP or PTP devices are not assigned drive letters :

> **Most MTP-compatible devices are not assigned drive letters; instead, they appear as "devices" in applications such as Windows Explorer.
>   Compared to devices that implement USB mass storage, such devices
>   cannot be accessed programmatically by scripts or normal Windows
>   programs that depend on drive letters. Instead, files must be
>   manipulated using Windows Explorer or applications with specially
>   written MTP support.** Another disadvantage of MTP devices on Windows
>   is that file timestamps are not shown in Windows Explorer, although
>   they can be retrieved by opening the file Properties popup.

*source :* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol
In windows the background technology is named **Windows Portable Devices ( WPD )**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpdblog/2009/08/15/introducing-device-services/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd388998(v=vs.85).aspx

There is an API named Windows Photo Import API in Windows10 that is the support for PTP in windows ( screenshot is still image so you can use this ) and it works with javascript:

> With Windows 10, Microsoft introduced the Windows Photo Import API, a
>   new, fully asynchronous application programming interface that is part
>   of the Universal Windows Platform.
>
> The API can be consumed from Windows Store applications written in
>   JavaScript, C# and C++/CX, as well as from classic Win32/COM
>   applications written in C++, with the help of the Windows Runtime C++
>   Template Library (WRL), a modern successor to the respected Active
>   Template Library that many developers known and love, or using the
>   MIT-licensed Modern CPP framework from Kenny Kerr (references below).

*source :* https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/996318/Using-the-Windows-Photo-Import-API-Windows-Media-I

You have to search an application or API with WPD ( resp. MTP or PTP ) support and use it to access your phones internal storage.

In javascript is an implementation of PTP in **https://github.com/navjagpal/jsptp**

Currently there is no  library for MTP only a wrapper for `libmtp` in node.js ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/mtp  version 0.0.1 )